# How can I add a fragment inside view pager framgent

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a view pager .It contains three fragments. I need to add fragment on one of the view pager fragments when button clicked but I am having a problem in doing that.

this is the java code that should opens the new fragment but there is something wrong in it

```
        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle lessonData = new Bundle();
        LessonContent lessonContent = new LessonContent();
        lessonData.putString("lessonTitle", mylist.getTitle());
        lessonData.putString("lessonContent", mylist.getContent());
        lessonContent.setArguments(lessonData);
        ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(lessonContent, null)//I think this line is wrong
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.add(lessonContent, null)//I think this line is wrong
```

Should probably replace by:

```
.replace(R.id.yourfragmentcontainerid, lessonContent) // or android.R.id.content
```

And then it should work. The point is, it's not getting the layout to show so, it does not show anything.

Comment: But I am using view pager so I don't use a fragment container

Comment: So, try using `android.R.id.content` inside the replace.